# Proper length of an AF_UNIX socket when calling bind()

Tags: c, unix, sockets

[bind](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/bind.html)() needs a length of the sockaddr structure you've given it.
Now, for unix sockets, [sockaddr_un](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/un.h.html) is used

What's the proper ways of calculating the length of this when you've filled in the `sun_path` member ? I've seen multiple approaches:

```
socklen_t len = sizeof(sockaddr_un);
socklen_t len = offsetof(sockaddr_un,sun_path) + strlen(addr.sun_path);
socklen_t len = offsetof(sockaddr_un,sun_path) + strlen(addr.sun_path) + 1;
socklen_t len = sizeof(sockaddr.sun_family  ) + strlen(addr.sun_path);
```

And even other approaches. Is it ok to just take the sizeof(sockaddr_un) - or what is the proper way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)` is fine.

Take a look at the manpage `unix(7)`. The field `sun_path` is a character array that is part of the struct.

Comment: Yes, also `man 2 bind` has an example of binding a Unix domain socket.  http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/bind.html

Comment: That example just zeros the `sockaddr_un` structure and then only fills in `sun_family` and `sun_path`. Which sets the structure's `sun_len` field to zero on systems that have it (possibly all BSDs including MacOS). Is that portable?

Answer (score 10):

You are supposed to use `SUN_LEN` macro. Here's from `/usr/include/sys/un.h` on my Mac:

```
#if !defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE) || defined(_DARWIN_C_SOURCE)
/* actual length of an initialized sockaddr_un */
#define SUN_LEN(su) \
        (sizeof(*(su)) - sizeof((su)->sun_path) + strlen((su)->sun_path))
#endif  /* (!_POSIX_C_SOURCE || _DARWIN_C_SOURCE) */
```

#### Edit:

Yes, it's not portable and not POSIX, but we work on real platforms, don't we?

The thing is that you have to zero-terminate the path and the above code is as good as `sizeof( struct sockaddr_un )` but might save you a few bytes when copying from user to kernel but wastes a few cycles in `strlen`.

Look at how Linux handles that length (from http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.32/net/unix/af_unix.c#L200):

```
static int unix_mkname(struct sockaddr_un *sunaddr, int len, unsigned *hashp)
{
    if (len <= sizeof(short) || len > sizeof(*sunaddr))
        return -EINVAL;
    if (!sunaddr || sunaddr->sun_family != AF_UNIX)
        return -EINVAL;
    if (sunaddr->sun_path[0]) {
        /*
         * This may look like an off by one error but it is a bit more
         * subtle. 108 is the longest valid AF_UNIX path for a binding.
         * sun_path[108] doesnt as such exist.  However in kernel space
         * we are guaranteed that it is a valid memory location in our
         * kernel address buffer.
         */
        ((char *)sunaddr)[len] = 0;
        len = strlen(sunaddr->sun_path)+1+sizeof(short);
        return len;
    }

    *hashp = unix_hash_fold(csum_partial(sunaddr, len, 0));
    return len;
}
```

Here `len` is directly from third argument to `bind` system call, but `sunaddr` is already copied into kernel space with that length. You can't have address longer then `sizeof( sockadd_un )`. Kernel does the `strlen` anyway.

So yes, doing `sizeof( sockaddr_un )` is probably safer across the board, but telling kernel exact length doesn't hurt either.

Comment: I didn't know about `SUN_LEN`, and didn't vote you down either. But I was interested in where `SUN_LEN` came from, so I Google'd it, and found this very informative post: http://mail-index.netbsd.org/tech-net/2006/10/11/0008.html

Comment: `SUN_LEN` is not portable, and is not in POSIX.

Comment: @nos, the other way around - strlen is called for normal path.