# IPC QLocalSocket -> C, why is my connect failing ? connect failed: [2] (no such file?!)

Tags: python, c, macos, qt, sockets

I'm running this example http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-ipc-localfortuneserver-example.html

Using `cat <socket_name>` works fine, I even managed to connect with python.

However this unfortunately fails. -> connect() failed: [2][No such file or directory]  ? W H Y ¿

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define SOCK_PATH "/Users/Name/socket"

int main(void) {
    int sockfd = 0,n = 0, err = 0;
    char recvBuff[1024];
    struct sockaddr_un serv_addr;
    const char* const pcSocketName = SOCK_PATH;
    memset(recvBuff, '0' ,sizeof(recvBuff));
    if((sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0))< 0) {
        printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
        return 1;
    }
    serv_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    serv_addr.sun_path[0] = '\0';
    strncpy(serv_addr.sun_path+1, pcSocketName, strlen(pcSocketName));
    err = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    if(0 != err) {
        printf("connect() failed: [%d][%s]\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return(-1);
    }
    while((n = read(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1)) > 0) {
        recvBuff[n] = 0;
        if(fputs(recvBuff, stdout) == EOF) {
            printf("\n Error : Fputs error");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    if( n < 0) {
        printf("\n Read Error \n");
    }
    printf("Over..\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm running on MacOS, building with gcc. Parts of this code were put together from various places on the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The socket path copy line is wrong:

```
strncpy(serv_addr.sun_path+1, pcSocketName, strlen(pcSocketName));
```

You want to copy `pcSocketName` to `serv_addr.sun`. Also protection `strlen(pcSocketName)` does not make any sense here. You can use just

```
strcpy(serv_addr.sun_path, pcSocketName);
```

---

In the simple example `strcpy` is safe if we are sure that the length of `SOCK_PATH` is small enough to fit in the buffer `serv_addr.sun_path`. However, to avoid accidental errors or in more complex cases when the string length can vary it makes sense to protect from the potential overflow. The function `strncpy` can be used to copy no more than `sizeof(serv_addr.sun_path) - 1` bytes from `pcSocketName`. One byte is reserved for zero terminating character. If the length limit is reached in `strncpy` the last null character is not appended. So, it should be set manually:

```
serv_addr.sun_path[sizeof(serv_addr.sun_path) - 1] = '\0';
strncpy(serv_addr.sun_path, pcSocketName, sizeof(serv_addr.sun_path) - 1);
```

---

I guess that your code is based on [Can not connect to Linux "abstract" unix socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640826/can-not-connect-to-linux-abstract-unix-socket)

That resulted in the initial connecting issues. The first byte in `sun_path[]` should be zero (`serv_addr.sun_path[0] = '\0';`) to work with *abstract namespace UNIX sockets*. However such abstract namespace is a nonportable Linux extension:

- abstract namespace sockets are not supported on Mac OS X (and OS X)
- Qt `QLocalSocket` does not support it even on Linux: [QTBUG-16090](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-16090)

So, `QLocalSocket` works with the filesystem sockets. Such sockets should be accessed in C just by a null-terminated filesystem pathname in `sun_path`.

Comment: Concerning the protection, am I right in thinking that one or the other are enough but both redondant?

Comment: @thomas Yes, you can use either `strcpy` (your path length is small enough and you set it manually) or to be sure that the path fits into `serv_addr.sun_path` you can use `strncpy` and manually set the last zero byte. BTW, to clarify connecting issues I guess that your code is from the post about `abstract` sockets http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640826/can-not-connect-to-linux-abstract-unix-socket You can find that abstract sockets does not use real file names, but you have real file that can be used with `cat`.